# Cannot get view to inflate with custom ListView adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello I have been trying to create a custom adapter to display a listview of simple user information for quite some time with no luck. I have gone through countless tutorials, stackoverflowthreads etc. and changed my code more times than I can count but I have not been able to get the view to display without crashing. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Also, I can print out the user information that I pull from the database and it displays like it should, so all of the individual information is being pulled correctly, but I have been unsuccessful in displaying said information through a view.

Here is my logcat:

```
08-09 21:28:23.745 10009-10009/bubble.bubblev1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: bubble.bubblev1, PID: 10009
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bubble.bubblev1/bubble.bubblev1.content.Activity.UserMatchActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:487)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                     at bubble.bubblev1.content.Activity.UserMatchActivity.onCreate(UserMatchActivity.java:76)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

UserMatchActivity.java

```
public class UserMatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private static final String TAG = UserMatchActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    public ArrayList<User> matchList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView listView;
    private static ResultAdapter adapter;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_usermatch); //activity_match_main
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        matchList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
        String name = user.get("name");
        String email = user.get("email");
        String school = user.get("school");
        getMatches(school);
        adapter = new ResultAdapter(matchList, getApplicationContext());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                User users = matchList.get(position);
                Snackbar.make(view, "Name: "+users.getName()+"\n"+"School: "+users.getSchool()+"\n"+"Email: "+users.getEmail(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("No action", null).show();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    private void getMatches(final String school) {
        String tag_string_req = "get_matches";
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_SEARCH, new Response.Listener<String>() { //{
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {  //JSONObject response
                //Log.d(TAG, "User Match Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {   
                    JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(response);
                    boolean error = false;
                    String errortest = String.valueOf(error);
                    Log.d("error", errortest);
                    error = false;

                    //JSONArray jsonResultArray = jObj.getJSONArray("school");



                    if (!error) {
                        //JSONArray jsonResultArray = jObj.getJSONArray("school");  //match?
                        //Log.d("name",String.valueOf(jsonResultArray));
                        for (int i = 0; i < jObj.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject childJSONObject = jObj.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = childJSONObject.getString("name");
                            Log.d("name", String.valueOf(name));
                            String email = childJSONObject.getString("email");
                            Log.d("email", String.valueOf(email));
                            String school = childJSONObject.getString("school");
                            Log.d("school", String.valueOf(school));
                            //User usr = new User(childJSONObject);
                            User usr = new User(name, email, school);

                            matchList.add(usr);

                        }

                    } else {


                        String errorMsg = ("brokelol");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Match Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to search url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("school", school);
                return params;
            }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
}
```

ResultAdapter.java

```
public class ResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> implements View.OnClickListener {  //implements View.OnClickListener
    // private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<User> user;
    Context mContext;
    //private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ResultAdapter";

    private class ViewHolder {  //static
        TextView usrName;
        TextView usrSchool;
        TextView usrEmail;
    }

    //public ResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users)
    public ResultAdapter(ArrayList<User> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_usermatch, data);
        this.user = data;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Object object = getItem(position);
        User user=(User)object;
        /*switch (v.getId())
        {   for picture
            case R.id.item_info:
                Snackbar.make(v, "Name " +user.getName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("No action", null).show();
                break;
        }*/
    }
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        User user = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_usermatch, parent, false);
            viewHolder.usrName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resultName);
            viewHolder.usrEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resultEmail);
            viewHolder.usrSchool = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resultSchool);
            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
        viewHolder.usrName.setText(user.getName());
        viewHolder.usrEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
        viewHolder.usrSchool.setText(user.getSchool());


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

activity_usermatch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listMatches">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/MatchLayout">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultSchool"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="School"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</ListView>
```

I cannot divulge the entire application, but these are the the files involved with this activity.  I have no compiler errors, only runtime. Any help or advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot have any `<View>`s inside the `<ListView>` in your layout. That's not how `ListView` works. You need to move those to a separate layout file - e.g., `list_item.xml` - and inflate that in `getView()`, instead of `R.layout.activity_usermatch`.

Comment: Thank you this really helped get me on track!